# Selenium file download exiting without errors but file is nowhere on the system

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, button, download, css-selectors

I can't download the file even though there is no error code. There is nothing saved in my hard drive.

Screenshot of the Website:

[image: Screenshot of the Website]

Here is the code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

# Set up Selenium Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run in headless mode, without opening a browser window

# Set the path to your ChromeDriver executable

DRIVER_PATH = '/Users/hudso/OneDrive/Documents/UST course/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

# Navigate to the webpage
driver.get("https://www.barchart.com/etfs-funds/quotes/QQQ/options?expiration=2023-06-08-w")

# Find the element based on the provided CSS selector
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#main-content-column a.toolbar-button.download.ng-isolate-scope > i")

# Wait for 5 seconds
time.sleep(5)

# Perform a click action on the element
element.click()

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You see no errors because the download is working. It just doesn't save the file to the right directory.

Now I don't know which version of Selenium you are using so the code you'd have to use might vary from mine, but here's how I got it working:

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": "<directory>"
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

You need to specify where Selenium will save the file. Just exchange `<directory>` with the path you want the file to be saved in.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to click the download button manually, you will notice that after you click <kbd>download</kbd>, a pop-up appears and the website forces you to log-in first before it actually starts downloading(see the image below).

And in your code since you are clinking the button and immediately closing the browser, you do not have any errors.

[image]